# how can i change string value dynamically

Tags: android

such as:

strings.xml:

```
<resource>
   <string name="my_title">Train Video</string>
</resources>
```

i use this string in Java code many cases, such as:

```
String title = resources.getString(R.string.my_title) // title="Train Video"
textView.setText(title)
```

Now i get the new string valued "Train Video Demo" from server, i want to update the strings value so that when i using the following code to get new string:

```
String title = resources.getString(R.string.my_title) // title="Train Video Demo"
```

if i can't change Java code, how can i achieve it?

i know Facebook Android App can do it dynamically, i don't know it's program. Is there some blogs to explain this?

Answer (score 2):

so you want to change value dynamically for that you can add **%1$s** in your string file

**string.xml**

```
<resource>
   <string name="my_title">Title: %1$s</string>
</resources>
```

**Activity.kt**

```
resources.getString(R.string.my_title, title)
```

Here the title is dynamic value can be from API or static list.

Comment: Thanks, but no. i don't want to use '%1s' in my string file, because the string file is fixed.

Comment: %1$s this thing will help you to update your string dynamically otherwise you have to use value coming from the response and set it to text field like label.text = value

Answer (score 0):

you can't change the values in strings.xml, so you should just start off by getting all the values you need from the server to begin with, then you can cache those by using a database, you could even use a pre-populated database when releasing your app, then read those values out of the db when you need them. to update your values, make an api call, check if there are new values available, update your local db, app continues to work as normal

Answer (score -1):

You can set the value of textview directly to the string you got.

```
textView.setText("Train Video Demo")
```

Comment: that's not what OP is asking, it's important to read and understand the entire question before jumping to an answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).